# RxJS switchMap/mergeMap resulting in Obserable<unknown>

Tags: typescript, rxjs, tsconfig, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

### Intro

I am trying to use RxJS in a TypeScript project but I am seeing strange behavior when using the `switchMap` and `mergeMap` pipeline operator where the type is being lost somewhere. I have separate TypeScript project (react app) that includes the same version of RxJS and I am not seeing this behavior. Both projects are being evaluated by the same version of TypeScript (4.2.3). I am at a loss as to what might be wrong, any help would be appreciated.

### Context

Here is a simple test case that I created to demonstrate the problem. Copying this code into my other project compiles and works as expected. As you can see I have one source stream or type `Observable<number>` and when I map this into a `string` the output type is `Observable<string>`, which is correct. However, when I apply a `switchMap` and return a stream of a string, the type emitted by the call to pipe is `Observable<unknown>`

[image: Sample code]

Here you can see the IDE highlighting the type mismatch

[image: TypeScript error]

I examining the type of the `switchMap` operation itself shows that the type is being inferred correctly going in, but the type is lost in the return value. I have inspected the `OperatorFunction` type and I don't see anything wrong (and is no different in the other project)

[image: switchMap type]

### Config

Given the problem above and the fact that this works in another project, makes me think that the problem is in my TypeScript config. After half an hour of switching things on and off I have seem glimmers of hope but nothing has worked. Here is my `tsconfig.json` and I am using TypeScript 4.2.3:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                         /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                                   /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                             /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                             /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                           /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'. */
     "declaration": true,                         /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
     "declarationMap": true,                      /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
     "sourceMap": true,                           /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                             /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
     "outDir": "./lib",                              /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                             /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                           /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                     /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                      /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                              /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                       /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                  /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                     /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
     "noImplicitAny": true,                       /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
     "strictNullChecks": true,                    /* Enable strict null checks. */
     "strictFunctionTypes": true,                 /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
     "strictBindCallApply": true,                 /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
     "strictPropertyInitialization": true,        /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
     "noImplicitThis": true,                      /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
     "alwaysStrict": true,                        /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
     "noUnusedLocals": true,                      /* Report errors on unused locals. */
     "noUnusedParameters": true,                  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
     "noImplicitReturns": true,                   /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,          /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
//     "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": false,            /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
//     "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,  /* Require undeclared properties from index signatures to use element accesses. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",                  /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                             /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                 /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                              /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                             /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                                 /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,        /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                    /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                            /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                               /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                     /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                       /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
     "experimentalDecorators": true,              /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,               /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "scripthost",
      "es2015.collection",
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules/**/*"]
}
```

and just for completeness, here is the code from the pictures above

```js
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { map, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const source = new Observable<number>();

const switchMapToString: Observable<string> = source.pipe(
    switchMap(n => of(`${n}`)),
);

const mapToString: Observable<string> = source.pipe(
    map(n => `${n}`),
);
```

Comment: Any chance you can upload a repository for that? It'd be easiest to reproduce this elsewhere, and I assume it wouldn't work. Did you try some basic things like restarting the IDE, deleting node_modules etc.?

Comment: Your code is working correctly in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66615681?file=index.ts).  What versions of TypeScript and RxJS are you using in your failing project?

Comment: What happens when you annotate the project function? `switchMap((n:number):Observable<string> => of(\`${n}\`))`

Comment: also, if you haven't already, delete node_modules and reinstall, just to rule that out.

Comment: @IngoBürk unfortunately I can't post a link to the repository but I have now tried deleting node_modules and restarting my IDE and it is still wrong (as well as the "Invalidate Cache / Restart" feature in WebStorm).

Comment: @BizzyBob Thanks for checking but the question is regarding the types not compiling. I am running TypeScript 4.2.3 and RxJS 6.6.3

Comment: @Ozan I have just tried adding explicit types to the lambda and it didn't make a difference (and as I mentioned above I have tried deleting node_modules)